# REDIS usecase using large keys with small values

Tags: redis, use-case

I have a use-case for using redis that is a little bit different.
In my MySQL I have an entity, let's call it `HumanEntity`.   this `HumanEntity` has many to many relations.

`HumanEntity.Urls` - Many URLs per `HumanEntity`.
`HumanEntity.UserNames` - Many UserNames per `HumanEntity`.
`HumanEntity.Phones` ...
`HumanEntity.Emails` ...

in a normal one hour, the application creates hundreds of these many values.
The use-case is that, the application receives an HTTP call (100 per one second) with a `HumanEntity` value (Url or UserName or Phone or Email).

I need to scan my MySQL (1,000,000 records) and return back the `HumanEntity.Id(integer)` .
Since its ok to have some latency in the data integrity I thought about REDIS.

Can I store the values as a Redis `key` and the and the `HumanEntity.Id(integer)` as the value.
My API needs to return back the `HumanEntity.Id(integer)`.

does it make sense to have such long key and such short value? The URL, for example, maybe 1500 bytes and the value can be 1 byte.

What is the best redis method to implement that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the values are not unique then you may have some problem. Phones, emails or usernames maybe unique for user but i am not sure about url or any other property stored in your database. You may overwrite the value of an identifier with another user's.

If you don't have any problem like that; you may proceed with string types, Time complexity of `GET` and `SET` is O(1) - that's the best you may get.

In some cases such as checking whether the user used any coupon, you may use long(let's say 64 chars) user id as key, and 1 as value and use `EXISTS` to determine it. So it's valid to use long key and short value.